# Checking if inputted PHP code returns a value

Tags: php, eval

I'm trying to make sure that some PHP code entered into a textarea is valid and returns a value.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    if (!$return = eval($php_code)) {
        $error = 'The php code field must return a value.';
    }
}
catch (Throwable $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}

if (isset($error)) {
    die($error);
}
```

This does not appear to be working. It catches most of the errors, but if I enter something like `echo 'test';` it does not produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the whole code, but try to check eval(). I usually work with the next code as a example:

```
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with $nombre inside.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [eval function documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) you should enter something like this

```
'echo "test";'
```

not

```
echo 'test';
```